Deshabilitar un botón de formulario
Código para que cuando el valor del input sea menor a 250 el button se inhabilite y que cuando sea mayor o igual de 250 se habilite, en PHP.
Este es mi código.
<label for="cedula"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="cedula" 
name="student" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rainbow_documento']; ?>" 
autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" required="required">
<label for="balance"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="balance" 
name="balance" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rainbow_balance']; ?>" 
onkeyup="comprobar()" required="required">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="find" 
onclick="return comprobar()" disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;"> 
    Ver información del cliente
</button>


¿El valor de cuál de los input? ¿Solo cuando se carga la página o cada vez que se modifica el valor?

El valor del input BALANCE, solo cuando se carga la página, por que el valor viene de una tabla llamada STUDENT.

PHP es un lenguaje backend, por lo que no puede cambiar cosas en la vista una vez se haya renderizado. Para ello necesitas Javascript, como bien ya has puesto en parte del código.
Para hacer las pruebas acá le eliminé al input la parte:
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rainbow_balance']; ?>"
Y le puse 230, pero en tu desarrollo lo debes dejar como estaba.
-Edit- Necesitas que se ejecute inicialmente la condición del botón. Posiblemente haya una mejor solución, pero se me ocurre que ejecutes la misma función comprobar() cuando carga la página con window.onload.


window.onload = function() {
    comprobar();
}

function comprobar() {
  let inp = document.getElementById("balance");
  let butt = document.getElementById("find");
  butt.disabled = (inp.value >= 250) ? false : true;
}
<form>
<label for="balance"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="balance" 
name="balance" value="230" 
onkeyup="comprobar()" required="required">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="find" 
onclick="" disabled="disabled" style="width: 100%;"> 
    Ver información del cliente
</button>
<form>




Gracias por tu respuesta, el código JS es el que necesito, pero lo hace cada vez que se modifica el valor, y yo lo necesito solo cuando se carga la página, por que el valor viene de una tabla llamada STUDENT.

@user400020 no soy muy bueno en JS, pero se me ocurre que ejecutes la misma función en la carga de la página con window.onload, tal como lo edité en el código. Posiblemente haya una mejor forma, pero creo que así funciona.

Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta Quedo perfecto como  lo necesitaba.
